# Garbage collection change from Java 1.4 to Java 6?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

We have recently upgraded one of our applications from Java 1.4 to Java 6.

With some load & performance tests, we observed that available memory stayed in general at much lower levels in Java 6 than at what it used to be with Java 1.4.

After some profiling on the app with Java 6, we noticed that many objects no longer referenced by any other objects (i.e. candidates for garbage collection) stayed in memory and were apparently never garbage collected. We took that as the explanation for the lower available memory.

Question is: did the way garbage collection behaves changed from Java 1.4 to Java 6?

Comment: <wiseass> I think it's save to assume that *all* parts of the JVM, including the GC, improved during all those years... </wiseass>

Comment: Are you sure the objects are genuine candidates for collection?  Do they get collected if you initiate a collection through JConsole?

Comment: Java 7 is meant to have even more 'optimizations' on the garbage collector.

Comment: Have you actually _forced_ the JVM to clean thoroughly?

Comment: @Jon Freedman, yes, they are genuine candidates.

Comment: @delnan, not necessarily. JVM overall performance has definitely improved over the years. The JVM is one of the world's most heavily-optimized pieces of software. However, in particular case of the GC, I'm concerned about monitoring. Basically, our app prints to the log the amount of free mem from time to time. Now that the GC doesn't act until when it's really necessary, when memory is low, we're not sure if it's just about waiting for the GC to free mem or if there are really running processes using almost all memory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> did the way garbage collection behaves changed from Java 1.4 to Java 6?

Definitely!

Java 1.4 to Java 6 is a pretty long timespan (almost 5 years between the [initial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.4_.28February_6.2C_2002.29) [releases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6_.28December_11.2C_2006.29) and more than 8 years between the [initial 1.4 release](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.4_.28February_6.2C_2002.29) and [the current Java 6 release](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6_Update_21), according to [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)).

Many changes and optimizations are applied in that time and you should not really care as long as your program still works.

Having more used memory only means that the JVM doesn't waste time with garbage collection when it doesn't need to. If you want it to use less memory, then you should reduce the maximum heap (or otherwise tweak the JVM parameters; [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html) explains how to do that in Java 5, much of the advice is still applicable).

It's somewhat different if you actually get `OutOfMemoryError` that you didn't get previously. Then you should check how you use weak and soft references or as a last resort try to find out if you hit a JVM bug.

Answer (score 5):

There have been several optimizations on garbage collecting between 1.4 and 5 and between 5 and 6.

Oracle/Sun have some whitepapers on the performance differences online:

[Java 5 Performance White Paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20070206025504/http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/5.0_performance.html#2.11)

[Java 6 Performance White Paper](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/6performance.html#2.2)

Answer (score 3):

Java SE changed a lot in 8 years.

Concerning the garbage collector, it has been improved a lot with [Java SE 6](http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/6_performance.html#2.2).
In Java SE 6 Update 14 the new [Garbage First](http://blogs.oracle.com/theplanetarium/entry/java_vm_trying_a_new) GC was introduced.

Comment: While G1 is shipped with releases >= u14, it is not enabled by default in any Java 6 release, as far as I know.

Comment: It isn't, you have to activate it with `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC`

Comment: HEBERT: just be prepared for some segfaults and crashes of the VM, unless you are using G1 with Java 7.